# Probability question about a game

Tags: probability

> On average, the time elapsed until the office printer receives a new job is 4
> minutes. 7 minutes have passed since the printer did not print anything. The boss will propose a game: if the printer will receive a new task in the next 4 minutes, you will receive a bonus of 100 EUR; if not, you will have to
> pay for the lunch order worth 80 EUR. What is the average earnings?

I think that this is a exponential distribution with $\lambda = 1/7$ and I need to find $\mathbb{P}(X \leq 11 | X \geq 7) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X\in [ 7,11 ])}{\mathbb{P}(X \geq 7)}$, and compute $\mathbb{E}[X]$ but I see that the answer is not correct. Can you help me please? Thanks you!

Comment: What did you obtain for that probability? Something that may help to remember is that the exponential distribution is memoryless.

Comment: @K.Jiang I think I don't know how to interpret the problem. Can you offer me a method to solve it please? Is not a homework. I try to understand this better...

Comment: I obtained $\mathbb{P}("\text{I win 100 EUR}") = 1-\frac{1}{e}$ and $\mathbb{P}("\text{I lose 80 EUR}") = \frac{1}{e}$. So $\mathbb{E}[X] =  (1-\frac{1}{e})*100 - 80 * \frac{1}{e} = 33.78... $ But this isn't the correct answer

Comment: One of this needs to be correct answer: A) -13.782 B) -18.72883 C) -18.70829 D) -11.12265 E) -9.98069

Comment: I agree with your answer. Maybe it is an error with the problem statement?

Comment: Hmm. I don't know. I thought that I'm wrong

Comment: I guess the trick is how to understand the statement of "if the printer will receive a new task in the next 4 minutes". If you read it as "if the printer will receive at least one new task in the next 4 minutes", then your answer is correct. However, if you read it as "if the printer will receive exactly one new task in the next 4 minutes", then the answer of A) -13.782 is correct.

Comment: @user295357 and how I can compute the probability "if the printer will receive exactly one new task"?

Comment: @MathLearner  I think the number (k) of new works occurring in a time interval $T=4$ follows Poison distribution with the mean of $\lambda = rT=1$, where $r=1/4$ is the average number of works per minute. Thus, the probability that exactly one work occurs in next 4 minutes is $P(k=1) = exp(-1)$, which happens to be the same as $P(k=0)$.  The rest part is straightforward.